# Show convergence of series using Taylor series: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(e^{\frac1{\large\sqrt{n}}}-1-\frac1{\sqrt{n}} - \frac{1}{2n}\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

I am trying to prove convergence of following series using Taylor series.
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}-1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} - \frac{1}{2n}\right)$$

$$e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}=1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{2n} +\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^2 r\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$$

When $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\to 0$ then $r\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\to 0$. So if $n\to\infty$ then $r\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\to 0$ 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}+r\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$$

I am not sure about convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$.  I can't show it. Could you help me ?

Comment: The last (displayed) equation doesn't seem right -- meaning it doesn't agree with what you had previously. Subtracting the first three terms from the expansion for $e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}$ leaves you with the last term in your second equation, where you have $\frac{1}{n}$, not $\frac{1}{n^2}$ and times, not plus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**. One may write, by the Taylor series expansion, as $n \to \infty$, 
$$
e^{\large\frac1{\sqrt{n}}}=1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{6n^{3/2}} +\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^3 r\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)
$$ with $r(u) \to 0$ as $u \to 0$, giving that, there exists some $n_0>0$ such that $\displaystyle \left|r\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right|\le1$ for all $n \ge n_0$, that is
$$
0 \le\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^3 r\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\le\frac{1}{n^{3/2}},\qquad \qquad n\ge n_0,
$$ giving the convergence of 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(e^{\large\frac1{\sqrt{n}}}-1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{2n}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{6n^{3/2}}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^3 r\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)
$$by comparison to a convergent $p$-series.

Comment: $e^{\large\frac1{\sqrt{n}}}=1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{2n} +\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^3 r\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$  For me, it should be $e^{\large\frac1{\sqrt{n}}}=1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{2n} +\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^2 r\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$  peano form of reminder - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem

Comment: @Haskell Fun True. Hence you just have to add a term in your expansion, as edited above. Thanks!